# Evaluating limits of integral

Tags: limits

I am struggling with this question.

$I_m = \int_{0}^{1}(\frac{x^m}{x^2+x+1})dx$ Find $\lim_{m\to\infty}(m*I_m)$

I tried using the multiplicative property of limits but that ended up with $0 * \infty$ which is undefined (as I calculated $\lim_{m\to\infty}(I_m)=0$.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: @BrianMoehring School

Comment: I'd hope for a bit more information than that.  Which class are you taking, and what was the context for the exercise [i.e. what methods appeared in the lesson surrounding this question]?

Answer (score 1):

Outside a neighborhood of $1$, the integrand tends to $0$ uniformly and exponentially which contributes nothing to the limit.  Therefore
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} (m\cdot I_m) = \lim_{m\to\infty} \left(m\cdot \int_0^1 \frac{x^m}{1^2+1+1}\,dx\right) = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m}{3(m+1)} = \frac13.$$